# ReferenceError: client is not defined | client.userSettings = new Collection();

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

i have coded a discord bot but i have a problem, when i start the bot i have this problem : "ReferenceError: client is not defined", i have downloaded requirements ect...

The client :

```html
client.userSettings = new Collection();
```

My interactionCreate.js :

```html
// Check the guide at the beginning if you don't understand paths.
const User = require("../Models/User");
const cmd = client.Commands.get(interaction.commandName);
if (cmd) {
  let user = client.userSettings.get(interaction.user.id);
  // If there is no user, create it in the Database as "newUser"
  if (!user) {
    const findUser = await User.findOne({ Id: interaction.user.id });
    if (!findUser) {
      const newUser = await User.create({ Id: interaction.user.id });
      client.userSettings.set(interaction.user.id, newUser);
      user = newUser;
    } else;
  }

  if (cmd.premium && user && !user.isPremium) {
    interaction.followUp(`You are not premium user`);
  } else {
    cmd.run({ client, interaction, args });
  }
}
```

My User.js :

```html
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

// The heart of the User, here is everything saved that the User does.
// Such as Levels, Courses, Premium, Enrolled, XP, Leaderboard.
const user = mongoose.Schema({
  Id: {
    type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  isPremium: {
    type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  premium: {
    redeemedBy: {
      type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Array,
      default: null,
    },

    redeemedAt: {
      type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Number,
      default: null,
    },

    expiresAt: {
      type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Number,
      default: null,
    },

    plan: {
      type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.String,
      default: null,
    },
  },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("user", user);
```

Please help me i very need help pls, thanks you.

Comment: The error tells you everything.  `client` is not defined in your `interactionCreate.js` filed.

Comment: And how i define it pls

Comment: `const client = <whatever you want to be>` (we have no idea what this is but presumably you do!) [Or possibly it's something you need to import from another file/library but forgot to do the import? It's really not clear from your question!]

Comment: I dont understand

Comment: Take a look at the documentation on [this page](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/event-handling.html#reading-event-files) for how to create a boilerplate interactionCreate.js file. You should be able to access the client via the `interaction` object. You should not be re-creating it.

Comment: I dont understand i already added `const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });` in my interactionCreate.js

Answer (score 0):

Just utilize the client that you've passed to your commad:

```
  if (cmd.premium && user && !user.isPremium) {
    interaction.followUp(`You are not premium user`);
  } else {
    cmd.run({ **client**, interaction, args });
  }
}
```

Also it'd be good to see how your command looks.